# Getting a single ID from loop using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a method that groups items with the same productID together and then adds their quantity together for items in the shopping cart. Now I am trying to add to it where it also adds the quantity from a page that adds to the cart. So in a call to this method I send the productid and quantity selected by the user to add to the total quantity. But the problem I run into is comparing the productids of the items being sent to this method and the ones being grouped together.

Here is what I have below, the commented parts is what I attempted to do to fix this but found out my thoughts were wrong on it.

```
double totalQty = 0;
bool isQtyValid = true;

List<ShoppingCartDTO> shoppingList = ShoppingCart.Fetch(string.Format("WHERE SessionID='{0}'", sessionID)); 
foreach (ShoppingCartDTO temp in shoppingList)
 {
    var groupList = shoppingList.GroupBy(item => item.ProductID);
    foreach (var m in groupList)
     {                    
        //var productID = m.Select(p => p.ProductID);
        //int prodID = Convert.ToInt32(productID);
        //if (ProductID == prodID)
        //{
             var sum = m.Sum(i => i.Quantity);
             totalQty = sum;
             //totalQty += qty;
             isQtyValid = CheckQty(totalQty, temp.ProductID, temp.CustomerID);
        //}
     }
 }
```

If anyone can provide some pointers or ideas I would really appreciate it. If it could use more explaining I can do that as well, or if you would like to see more code that I am using I can add that too.

Thank you to anyone that can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You grouped by the product ID, so it is the [`Key`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb343251.aspx) of your group:

```
foreach (var m in groupList)
{                    
    var productID = m.Key;
    // The rest of your code.
}
```

Comment: yes this would be exactly the answer i need! Thank you for your help, guess I was over thinking things.